# Do F-1 students need a visa to visit Paris and Amsterdam during layovers?

Tags: indian-citizens, layovers, paris, amsterdam, f1-visas

I am an Indian citizen with F-1 status travelling from the U.S. to India. I am going to have a layover of 12 hours in Paris while on my way to India and another layover of 6 hours in Amsterdam while returning from India. Do I need any visas for sightseeing Paris and Amsterdam during the respective layovers?

Answer (score -3):

Yes, you need a visa, called the **“Uniform Schengen” short-stay visa**. You can see all the details on the [French Embassy's website](http://www.ambafrance-in.org/What-type-of-visa-do-you-need-for), but your case is the following:

> - You wish to visit France and other Member States of the Schengen Area (including France) for a maximum period of 90 days per semester for various purposes (tourism, shopping, business trip, visiting a relative/friend, participation in an exhibition/ fair/ conference, studies, internships, artistic events, research, etc.): **“Uniform Schengen” short-stay visa**

Note that, even if you didn't leave there airport in Paris, you would still need a transit visa:

> - You simply wish to transit through a French airport (without accessing French national territory):  **Airport transit visa**

Comment: Are you sure about that last part? Wouldn't the valid US visa exempt them from the normal airport transit visa requirement they'd otherwise have as an Indian citizen?

Comment: I don't find anywhere a mention that having a valid US visa exempt you from anything… and why should it? It gives you rights to enter US territory, but is not otherwise recognized by France. But it's hard to prove a negative like that :)

Comment: I'd suggest you read the answer to the canonical [Do I need a visa to transit in the Schengen area?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-in-the-schengen-area) question - it covers these sorts of exemptions

Comment: @Gagravarr and the links in the answer you linked (specifically [this EU document](http://ec.europa.eu/dgs/home-affairs/e-library/documents/policies/borders-and-visas/visa-policy/docs/annex_7b_atv-national_lists.en.pdf)) confirm that **Indian passeport holders need an airport transit visa in French airports, even if then don't exit the international zone**.

Comment: I'm not disputing that, which is certainly the default case, but if you look at the linked answer you'll see that there are exemptions from those normal rules for people holding visas from certain countries

Comment: @Gagravarr I see this statement, indeed, in the linked answer… but it is not sourced and I, for one, cannot find a confirmation on any of the official French websites I looked at.

Comment: Might be best if you added a query to that effect to the answer, and hopefully the person who posted it can add the references and clear this up!

Comment: This web page makes it pretty clear that @Gagravarr is right: http://www.consulfrance-washington.org/spip.php?article383

Comment: (-1) As @Gagravarr explained, this answer is incorrect with respect to airport transit. The source for that, duly mentioned in my answer to the other question, is the [Schengen visa code](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/HTML/?uri=CELEX:32009R0810&from=EN), specifically article 3(5)(c). But really since you quite obviously haven't read it, it's a bit disingenuous to hide behind your own inability to read and understand the main regulation on the topic to resist making changes to your answer.

Comment: Besides, as @Louis has just shown, there are many French sources that also explain those rules, including [diplomatie.gouv.fr](http://www.diplomatie.gouv.fr/fr/venir-en-france/formalites-d-entree-en-france/article/quel-visa-pour-transiter-par-un-aeroport-situe-en-france).